# gcc -fstack-limit-(symbol|register) what is "signal is raised at run time"

Tags: gcc, stack-overflow, instrumentation

[Docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options)

> Generate code to ensure that the stack does not grow beyond a certain
>   value, either the value of a register or the address of a symbol. If a
>   larger stack is required, a signal is raised at run time. For most
>   targets, the **signal is raised** before the stack overruns the boundary,
>   so it is possible to catch the signal without taking special
>   precautions.
>
> For instance, if the stack starts at absolute address ‘0x80000000’ and
>   grows downwards, you can use the flags
>   -fstack-limit-symbol=__stack_limit and -Wl,--defsym,__stack_limit=0x7ffe0000 to enforce a stack limit of 128KB. Note that this may only work with the GNU linker.
>
> You can locally override stack limit checking by using the
>   no_stack_limit function attribute (see Function Attributes).

What is the "signal"? Does it require some OS interface? Should there be documentation as to what ID this signal has so that I can catch it?

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/ might be useful

Comment: @rogerdpack so are you saying Linux is required to use this option?

Comment: dunno, maybe windows has a similar mechanism? https://feepingcreature.github.io/handling.html

Answer (score 1):

I have just now myself run into the same question.

For x86 the signal will be "SIGILL", for illegal instruction. This is because GCC maps the "trap_if" RTL primitive to the x86 [`ud2`](https://mudongliang.github.io/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_318.html) instruction, which once executed will generate the signal.

For example, here is some source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef N
#define N 100000
#endif

register uintptr_t stack_limit asm ("r12");

void foo();

__attribute__((no_stack_limit))
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int ret = 0;
  stack_limit = (uintptr_t)(&ret - 1000);

  foo();
  return ret;
}

void foo()
{
  char *ch = (char *)alloca(N);
  printf("Now in foo\n");
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -ggdb -O0 -fstack-limit-register=r12 -o stack-lim stack-lim.c -fstack-usage -DN=3922`

Experimentally, `-DN=3921` will work ok, and `-DN=3922` will trigger it (on my machine), which is in the right ballpark considering how crude it is.

And here is the consequent disassembly in `gdb`. Notice the "ud2" instruction is conditionally executed by the `jae` before it.

```
   ...
B+>│0x555555554707 <foo+8>  mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   │0x555555554710 <foo+17> mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   │0x555555554714 <foo+21> xor    %eax,%eax
   │0x555555554716 <foo+23> mov    $0x10,%eax
   │0x55555555471b <foo+28> sub    $0x1,%rax
   │0x55555555471f <foo+32> add    $0xf62,%rax
   │0x555555554725 <foo+38> mov    $0x10,%ecx
   │0x55555555472a <foo+43> mov    $0x0,%edx
   │0x55555555472f <foo+48> div    %rcx
   │0x555555554732 <foo+51> imul   $0x10,%rax,%rax
   │0x555555554736 <foo+55> mov    %rsp,%rdx
   │0x555555554739 <foo+58> sub    %r12,%rdx
   │0x55555555473c <foo+61> cmp    %rax,%rdx
   │0x55555555473f <foo+64> jae    0x555555554743 <foo+68>
   │0x555555554741 <foo+66> ud2
   │0x555555554743 <foo+68> sub    %rax,%rsp
   │0x555555554746 <foo+71> mov    %rsp,%rax
   ...
```

And here is the relevant snippet of the same assembly, annotated with RTL by using `-fdump-rtl -dP` options, like so:

`$ gcc -ggdb -O0 -fstack-limit-register=r12 -S -o stack-lim.s stack-lim.c -fstack-usage -DN=3922 -dP -fdump-rtl-final`

Notice the `(trap_if)` becomes `ud2`:

```
...
#(insn 10 39 11 2 (parallel [
#            (set (reg:DI 1 dx [94])
#                (minus:DI (reg:DI 1 dx [94])
#                    (reg:DI 41 r12)))
#            (clobber (reg:CC 17 flags))
#        ]) "stack-lim.c":24 274 {*subdi_1}
#     (nil))
        subq    %r12, %rdx      # 10    *subdi_1/1      [length = 3]
#(insn 11 10 12 2 (set (reg:CC 17 flags)
#        (compare:CC (reg:DI 1 dx [94])
#            (reg:DI 0 ax [92]))) "stack-lim.c":24 8 {*cmpdi_1}
#     (nil))
        cmpq    %rax, %rdx      # 11    *cmpdi_1/1      [length = 3]
#(jump_insn 12 11 31 2 (set (pc)
#        (if_then_else (geu (reg:CC 17 flags)
#                (const_int 0 [0]))
#            (label_ref 15)
#            (pc))) "stack-lim.c":24 627 {*jcc_1}
#     (nil)
# -> 15)
        jnb     .L5     # 12    *jcc_1  [length = 2]
#(insn 13 31 14 3 (trap_if (const_int 1 [0x1])
#        (const_int 6 [0x6])) "stack-lim.c":24 1005 {trap}
#     (nil))
        ud2     # 13    trap    [length = 2]
.L5:
#(insn 16 32 17 4 (parallel [
#            (set (reg/f:DI 7 sp)
#                (minus:DI (reg/f:DI 7 sp)
#                    (reg:DI 0 ax [92])))
#            (clobber (reg:CC 17 flags))
#        ]) "stack-lim.c":24 274 {*subdi_1}
#     (nil))
        subq    %rax, %rsp      # 16    *subdi_1/1      [length = 3]
#(insn 17 16 18 4 (set (reg:DI 0 ax [93])
#        (reg/f:DI 7 sp)) "stack-lim.c":24 81 {*movdi_internal}
#     (nil))
        movq    %rsp, %rax      # 17    *movdi_internal/4       [length = 3]
...
```

I suspect the reason it is not well documented is because it is machine-specific as to which signal gets emitted, and indeed if such functionality is implemented at all. Although I do agree that the behavior for each target ought to be documented.